# Largest square written as $p^2+pq+q^2$ where $p, q$ are primes?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

I got this problem from the website Brilliant, but I have doubts about the solution presented there:
$(p+q)^2-k^2=pq$

$(p+q+k)(p+q-k)=pq$

Now either $(p+q+k)=p$ and $(p+q-k)=q$ (which doesn't work), or $(p+q+k)=pq$ and $(p+q-k)=1$ . Solving the second system of equations, we get the only solution of $(3, 5)$ I really don't think this statement is true. What if for example $(p+q-k)=(pq)^{1/4}$ and $(p+q+k)=(pk)^{3/4}$ ? If my doubts are correct, what is the real way to solve this question? Thanks.

Comment: How did you solve the second system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $p$ and $q$ are primes, $(pq)^{1/4}$ is not an integer. The fundamental theorem of arithmetic (or unique prime factorization theorem) immediately implies taht the only factorizations of $pq$ in positive integers are $p\cdot q$ and $1\cdot(pq)$, so the argument is correct.

Comment: Oh thanks how stupid of me I didn't even think

Comment: @Ovi: You’re welcome. (And I expect that we’ve all experienced that kind of blind spot a time or two!)

Comment: One additional question: how do you solve the second system of equations?

Answer (score 1):

All solutions to $$ p^2 + p q + q^2 = k^2   $$ with $p,q,k > 0$ and $\gcd(p,q,k) = 1$ ***but no requirement about primes***, are given by 
$$ p = u^2 + 2 u v, \; \; q = v^2 - u^2, \; \; k = u^2 + u v + v^2,      $$ with coprime $v > u > 0.$ See  [120 DEGREES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle#Integer_triangles_with_a_120.C2.B0_angle).

Since $p = u(u+2v), \; \; q = (v-u)(v+u),$ the only way to get both prime is $u=1, v=2,$ because we need both $u=1, \; \; v-u=1.$