# $p^2 + pq+q^2=n^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is $7^2 = 3^2+3 \cdot 5 + 5^2$ the only square that can be represented as $p^2 + pq + q^2$ where $p$ and $q$ are primes?

I have checked  all $n^2$ for $n \le 10^5$.

I don't think any elementary modular argument will work, because
$p^2 + p \cdot(-p) + (-p)^2 = p^2$.

Comment: As a cheap remark:  we can rewrite as $(p+q)^2-n^2=pq\implies (p+q-n)(p+q+n)=pq$.  your example has $p+q-n=1$... surely that is inevitable?

Comment: Indeed, if $p>q$ then we only need consider $p+q-n=q\implies p=n$ which is absurd.

Comment: Ah, but $p+q=n+1\implies (n+1)^2-pq=n^2\implies 2n+1=pq$ despite the fact that $n=p+q+1≤2p+1$ (assuming $p≥q$)  That should quickly bound $n$.

Comment: As a final remark, $n≤2p+1\implies 2n+1≤4p+3\implies pq≤4p+3\implies q≤3$, and so on.

Comment: Continuing on from lulu, with $ q = 2, $  $(p+2)^2 > p^2 + 2p + 4 >  (p+1)^2$. With $ q = 3$, $(p+2)^2 > p^2 + 3p + 9 > (p+1)^2$ when $ p > 5$. So we just have to check $(5, 3)$ which turns out to work.

Comment: duplicate: [Largest square written as $p^2+pq+q^2$ where $p, q$ are primes?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/450012/largest-square-written-as-p2pqq2-where-p-q-are-primes)

Comment: Robert, in Mordell, Diophantine Equations, page 47,  Theorem 4 says that all (primitive)  isotropic vectors of an indefinite  ternary quadratic form   are produced by one or more parametrizations of Pythagorean Triple type. For your form $x^2 +xy + y^2 - z^2,$  one recipe suffices, as 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_triangle#Integer_triangles_with_a_120%C2%B0_angle

Comment: writing $c^2 = a^2 + ab + b^2$  primitive we have, $m>n>0,$  $a = m^2 - n^2 = (m+n)(m-n) \; , \; \; $  and $b= 2mn + n^2 = n(2m+n)\; , \; \; $  and $c = m^2 + mn + n^2 \; . \; \;$   To get $a,b$ prime each smaller factor must be $1,$   so $m-n=1$  and $n=1$ As at https://www.had2know.com/academics/integer-triangles-120-degree-angle.html